# Setup Feign client and Resource implementation in the same application

Tags: java, spring, netflix-feign

I have following class hierarchy

```
@RequestMapping("/resource")
interface Resource {
  @GetMapping
  String hello(); 
}

@FeignClient(name = "resource")
interface ResourceFeign extends Resource {

}

@RestController
class ResourceImpl implements Resource {
  // implementation ommitted
}
```

How can I setup all of them without getting following error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot
>   map 'com.example.client.ResourceFeign' method 
>   public abstract java.lang.String
>   com.example.rest.Resource.hello()
>   to {[/resource],methods=[GET]}: There is already
>   'resourceImpl' bean method public
>   String com.example.rest.ResourceImpl.hello()
>   mapped.   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:576)